# Node JS, Type Error: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'token')?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typeerror

I am trying to store my login id in session during  login, but there is a type error, Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'token').
What is wrong here? and how can I store my login id in session during login

the code looks like this,

```
      else if (val[0].usertype == 'shop'){
          console.log("Login Succesfull");
        
          // store values in session
          var sessData = req.session;
          console.log(val[0].login_id);
          sessData.token = val[0].login_id;

          res.redirect('shop')
        }else{
          res.redirect('login')
        }
```

[image: Here is the Image for Refference]

I am expecting id to be stored in the session, so I can use it in different situations.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like `req.session` (and thereby `sessData`) is an undefined object, are you sure you've configured [`express-session`](https://npmjs.com/package/express-session) correctly?